Using livewire 3 @script @endscript and @assets @endassets directives inside a laravel package
I am creating a laravel package to extract daily use blade components in my other projects. My blade components contain livewire @script @endscript tags as well as @assets  @endassets tags in the component blade view like this:
@assets
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@endassets

@script
  <script>
    console.log('inside edit user script');
    let input = document.querySelector('input[name=skills]');

    // initialize Tagify on the above input node reference
    let tagify = new Tagify(input);
  </script>
@endscript


Blade Component is registered in Package Service Provider's boot() method as follows:
  Blade::component('tagify', TagifyComponent::class);

But when registered from/within a laravel package, these @script and @assets tags, throw the following error:
Using $this when not in object context

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.
